# Get table data not in pivot table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

### The problem I wish to solve

I have three tables: `notification`, `user`, `user_viewed_notification`. `notification` and `user` have a many to many relationship. How do I get the fresh notifications for a particular user:

```
-- mock sql to explain
select * from notification where user = 1 and viewed = false
```

### Desired Result

Empty as `webuser_id = 1` is inside `user_viewed_notification` table

| notification_id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |

### SQL fiddle

```
select version();
```

| version() |
| --- |
| 5.7.39 |

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `*****`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `notification`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `notification`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notification` (
  `notification_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `notification`
--

INSERT INTO `notification` (`notification_id`, `title`, `content`) VALUES
(1, 'Test', 'This is a test notification');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `webuser`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `webuser`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webuser` (
  `webuser_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login_attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`webuser_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `webuser_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `webuser`
--

INSERT INTO `webuser` (`webuser_id`, `name`, `tel`, `address`, `email`, `password`, `role`, `login_attempts`) VALUES
(1, 'John', '123', 'Street', '...', '****', 69, 0),
(3, 'Johny', '123', 'Street', '.f..', '****', 61, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `webuser_viewed_notifications`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `webuser_viewed_notifications`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webuser_viewed_notifications` (
  `webuser_webuser_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notification_notification_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`webuser_webuser_id`,`notification_notification_id`),
  KEY `webuser_viewed_notifications_webuser_webuser_id_index` (`webuser_webuser_id`),
  KEY `webuser_viewed_notifications_notification_notification_id_index` (`notification_notification_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `webuser_viewed_notifications`
--

INSERT INTO `webuser_viewed_notifications` (`webuser_webuser_id`, `notification_notification_id`) VALUES
(1, 1);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `webuser_viewed_notifications`
--
ALTER TABLE `webuser_viewed_notifications`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `webuser_viewed_notifications_notification_notific_e0da5_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`notification_notification_id`) REFERENCES `notification` (`notification_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `webuser_viewed_notifications_webuser_webuser_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`webuser_webuser_id`) REFERENCES `webuser` (`webuser_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM `webuser_viewed_notifications`
```

| webuser_webuser_id | notification_notification_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

```
SELECT * FROM `notification`
```

| notification_id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | This is a test notification |

```
SELECT * FROM `webuser`
```

| webuser_id | name | tel | address | email | password | role | login_attempts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 123 | Street | ... | **** | 69 | 0 |
| 3 | Johny | 123 | Street | .f.. | **** | 61 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZEhkP4sI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `NOT EXISTS`.

```
select n.*
from notification n
where not exists (select 1 
                 from webuser_viewed_notifications wvn 
                 where wvn.notification_notification_id=n.notification_id
                 and wvn.webuser_webuser_id = 1 )    ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/DWW7t6yG

- NOT EXISTS performs in most straightforward way: just checks equality and returns TRUE or FALSE on the first hit / miss.
- LEFT JOIN / IS NULL either makes an additional table lookup or does not return on the first match and performs more poorly.

Comment: @bik555 using left join is a solution as well, but in your case EXISTS will perform better.